# Can I make `git merge` always conflict on file changes?

Tags: git, version-control, latex, git-merge

I am hoping I have a simple question for you, but I can't find an answer anywhere (I have been searching for 2 days, maybe I am dumb?). I am trying to develop a git workflow to collaboratively edit LaTeX files with my PhD adviser. The problem we face is due to the behavior of `git merge` (because it merges automagically). I want git to conflict anytime it sees a file change, even if it is an addition, subtraction, or minuscule change, is this possible? This way we can both pick and choose changes and continually push to master.

I am not opposed to using another tool, but I would prefer not to create a complicated branching system. I assume branching is unnecessary when 2-3 people are working on the same file. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that, but you can use [`--no-commit`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) so that even if it cleanly merges, the merge isn't committed automatically. That way you can review the changes before making the commit.

Comment: I was looking into that, but I am not sure it solves the problem. Is the previous version of the file still available? Can I `vimdiff` the two somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [vcsjones noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377725/can-i-make-git-merge-always-conflict-on-file-changes#comment45095554_28377725), you pretty much have to use `--no-commit` here, to stop the merge even when git thinks it went well.

Regarding your subsequent question, you can get git to extract the two being-merged versions of the file in a number of ways.  The simplest is probably to use `git show`.  (Note that this bypasses smudge filters, though.)

When the merge stops, `HEAD` names the current commit and `MERGE_HEAD` names the commit being merged-in (this assumes a two-parent merge in progress; I've never tried this with an octopus merge), so if you have file `foo.tex` that git thinks it has merged correctly, and you want to inspect it yourself, you could do this:

```
$ git show HEAD:foo.tex > foo.tex.head
$ git show MERGE_HEAD:foo.tex > foo.tex.merge_head
$ vimdiff foo.tex foo.tex.head foo.tex.merge_head
```

This particular naming scheme (adding `.head` and `.merge_head` suffixes) is not very clever and could fail if you actually have a "real" file named `foo.tex.head`, of course, so for a robust tool you'd want to make temporary directories instead.  This could actually make the process easier as you could use `git checkout` (which *does* apply smudge filters) to populate the temporary directories.  For instance, this is a bit wasteful (checks out the entire `HEAD` and `MERGE_HEAD` trees rather than each file as you go):

```
$ hd_tree=/tmp/head.$$ mhd_tree=/tmp/merge_head.$$
$ index=/tmp/index.$$
$ mkdir $hd_tree $mhd_tree
$ GIT_INDEX_FILE=$index GIT_WORK_TREE=$hd_tree git checkout HEAD -- .
$ GIT_INDEX_FILE=$index GIT_WORK_TREE=$mhd_tree git checkout MERGE_HEAD -- .
```

Now for each file `$f` that you wish to hand-inspect:

```
$ vimdiff $f $hd_tree/$f $mhd_tree/$f
```

When all done, `rm -rf $hd_tree $mhd_tree $index` to discard the temporary work-trees, and the dummy index.

To be less wasteful of file space (but use more processes), check out each file `$f` one at a time as you go, using the `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment setting as above.  (The `GIT_INDEX_FILE` is here because `checkout` writes through the index and you really don't want to overwrite git's merged version in `.git/index`.)

[Note that none of the above is tested; caveat emptor.]

Comment: That solves the problem! Although it isn't a viable solution for our workflow (it's slightly over complicated). Since we are only dealing with a few source files I decided to go to a two directory workflow. This way the adviser never commits to the student, and vice-versa. If a `git pull` results in changes one can manually update the files using a diff tool.

Answer (score 1):

Stop the merge from completing with `--no-commit`

Get a list of files that were changed on both sides by performing `git diff --name-only HEAD...MERGE_HEAD` and `git diff --name-only MERGE_HEAD...HEAD`

Redirect the two lists of files to `comm -12` to get just files that were modified by both branches.

Note the following

> ::, e.g. :0:README, :README A colon, optionally followed by a
>   stage number (0 to 3) and a colon, followed by a path, names a blob
>   object in the index at the given path. A missing stage number (and the
>   colon that follows it) names a stage 0 entry. During a merge, stage 1
>   is the common ancestor, stage 2 is the target branch’s version
>   (typically the current branch), and stage 3 is the version from the
>   branch which is being merged.

For each file listed in the comm output you can then call `git difftool`  (presuming that will invoke vimdiff for you) and specify any combination of :0:, :1:, :2:, :3: that you want to see various diffs.

Comment: Annoyingly—at least, I find it annoying, once git thinks a merge is resolved, the numbered index-stage-versions stop being available.  The `--no-commit` stops the merge process from committing, but the files git thinks are successfully merged, won't have `:1:foo` entries for instance.

Comment: Annoying indeed, I only tested with conflicted files.  I'll update my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I have a different use case where this works nicely: In my project, the release process involves forking a stable point of the master branch, and then letting a robot update some files with version info, perform a release, and merge back the result to master. If the commit that updates version info touches the same file as some concurrent commit upstream, then a human must review the result, so I want the robot's final merge step to fail. Your answer solves that problem.