# libgit2: option to consider any update to ours and theirs of a file a conflict

Tags: c, libgit2

I'd like to be able to consider any update to a file made in both "ours" and "theirs" a conflict, regardless of how trivial the resolution might be, or how close in proximity the lines of updated code are. I don't want conflicts to be automatically fixed, regardless of how simple they might appear.

I had tried setting the default git_merge_options (https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/type/git_merge_options), as well as read through the flags and file_flags options to see what they provide but did not see a way of doing this.

Conflicts are only detected with the defaults if they appear in the same "region" in both ours and theirs; How can I modify the options so that any file modified in both ours and theirs is marked as conflicted, regardless of how close in proximity the regions might be?

Comment: For a native git analog of what im trying to do, im basically looking for the same thing being asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377725/can-i-make-git-merge-always-conflict-on-file-changes but with libgit2 instead of command line git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by reading the include code files, wasn't obvious from the documentation. (the documentation is in general very good, but didn't have my particular answer)

If you set 'merge_opts.default_driver = "binary";' all files will get the binary merge treatment which is exactly what I'm looking for.

For reference refer to src/merge_driver.h. It explains in a comment:
/* Merge driver for unmergeable (binary) files: always produces conflicts */